# to create a socket to read image from url in linux

Tags: sockets

I want to write a socket program which read an image from an url and store it at a location.
I am familiar with basic of socket programming but never created such type of socket.
Below is the code to create a socket to read data from client which i want to modify for above mentioned problem.
Please help me with this.

Thank you

```
Code::

include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define sport 5000

int main(int argc,char **argv[])//Main function
{

struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
int m,sd,acceptsd,rc,i;
char command[]="hello\n";
if((sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
{
    perror("error in socket creation\n");
    exit(0);
}

memset(&serveraddr,0,sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_port=htons(sport);
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=(INADDR_ANY);
//serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
rc=bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr,sizeof(serveraddr));
if(rc<0)
{
    perror("srver bind error\n");
    close(sd);
    exit(-1);
}
rc=listen(sd,5);
if(rc<0)
{
    perror("listen error");
    close(sd);
    exit(-1);
}

printf("server is ready to accept connection\n");
printf("\n");
    acceptsd=accept(sd,NULL,NULL);
    if(acceptsd<0)
    {
        perror("error in accepting\n");
        exit(-1);
        close(sd);
    }


rc=send(acceptsd,command2,sizeof(command2),0);
    if(rc<0)
    {   
        perror("error in sending\n");
        close(acceptsd);
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }   

close(acceptsd);
close(sd);
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I want to modify the socket code to read an image from url and store it at a particular location

Comment: I do not have any idea where to start.if you can suggest me some links or examples to guide me in proper direction.

Comment: check this link you may get help from this,, doing same as you.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4790336/2722799

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to use TCP sockets **and** implement HTTP protocol to be able to access any URLs.

Implementing HTTP protocol handling on your own is a daunting and labour intensive task. A good start would be using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).